# Using Appium on Android real device, unable to find toolbar button

Tags: android, appium

i'm facing this issue... i'm trying to locate and click on the button "BROWSER", but (with appium and also with uiautomatorviewer) the toolbar seems cannot be found.

do someone  help me please?

Thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible to interact with this pop-up directly. However, you can click this button by coordinates.

Comment: yes, done in this way at moment... it should be the best locate exactly (with an xpath or id....etc..)that button...

Answer (score -1):

You can print all elements in your script using method: driver.getPageSources() and check if it is there

Comment: already done, but toolbar elements (browser, cut, copy) are not present.